# Share class definition with dll

Tags: c#, dll

Is it possible share class definition with a dll? I have in main program class definition and connection with SQL. I need some dll to export data to xml. But I don't know how to send data colection to dll. If this class is defined in "main" program.

For example 
Main code:

```
namespace A
{
    public void callMethod()
    {
        B.method(aa);
    }

    public class aa
    {
        public aa()
        {
            this.abList = new List<ab>();
        }
        public int number {get; set;}
        public List<ab> abList {get;set;}
    }

    public class ab
    {
        public string text {get; set;}
    }
}
```

DLL library:

```
namespace B
{
    public static void method(aa atribute) // ??
    {
        aa. //??
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the required references and using directives? Also, the question is pretty poorly written, you may want to revise it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a common library with either the class or a implemented interface in it and reference this by both projects.

So instead of

- MainProj

  - aa
- DllProject

you should have

- MainProj
- DllProject
- Common

  - aa

So you place the `aa` class inside the `Common` project and reference this by all other projects.

If you can not move `aa` out of `MainProj` you can use a common interface.
Define in `Common` something like:

```
public interface Iaa
{
    int number { get; set;}
    List<ab> abList { get; }
}
```

and implement that in aa:

```
public class aa : Iaa
{
    public aa()
    {
        this.abList = new List<ab>();
    }
    public int number {get; set;}
    public List<ab> abList {get;set;}
}
```

The  you can define the following in `DllProject`:

```
public static void method(Iaa atribute) // ??
{
    aa.number = ...
}
```